# Why can't I access my vi folder?

Tags: mongodb, path, terminal, root, cd

I keep getting this error on my terminal which stops me accessing the vi folder. I've been trying to set a path to the MongoDB bin and when experimenting on how to do this, I think I've broken the folder. Can someone please help?

```
Last login: Mon May 18 10:31:54 on console
-bash: export: `/Users/james.flan/Documents/Software/MongoDB/bin :/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin': not a valid identifier
AMAC02MX3APF8J3:~ james.flan$ cd
AMAC02MX3APF8J3:~ james.flan$ vi .bash_profile
-bash: vi: No such file or directory
AMAC02MX3APF8J3:~ james.flan$
```

**Expanded:**

```
AMAC02MX3APF8J3:~ james.flan$ cat ~/.bash_profile
-bash: cat: No such file or directory
AMAC02MX3APF8J3:~ james.flan$ 
AMAC02MX3APF8J3:~ james.flan$ /bin/cat ~/.bash_profile
export PATH= "/Users/james.flan/Documents/Software/MongoDB/bin :$PATH"
AMAC02MX3APF8J3:~ james.flan$
```

Comment: I suppose you have broken your `$PATH` variable. Can you `cat ~/.bash_profile` so we can see what's the problem?

Comment: I've tried but the same error appears

Comment: then do `/bin/cat ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: Done, please see updated verion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your `$PATH` variable. You have broken it, so `bash` does not find any utility out of your current working directory.

To fix your issue you can execute `vi` directly with the absolute path:

```
$ /usr/bin/vi ~/.bash_profile
```

Then edit your `$PATH` declaration line:

```
export PATH="/Users/james.flan/Documents/Software/MongoDB/bin:$PATH"
```

Then you can either start a new Terminal session, or in the same session do:

```
$ /bin/bash -l
```